# Почему не срабатывает привязка?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я хочу, чтобы при вводе в текстбоксы изменялись поля объекта NewNote (чтобы потом добавить этот объект в базу данных, этот код я закомментировал). При этом команды, определенные во ViewModel, работают исправно.

Модель:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVM
{
    class Note : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string title;
        private string text;
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace MVVM
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
/*        ApplicationContext DB;
        IEnumerable<Note> notes;*/
        RelayCommand addNote;
        Note newNote = new Note();

        public Note NewNote
        {
            get { return newNote; }
            set
            {
                newNote = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NewNote");
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand AddNote
        {
            get
            {
                return addNote ??
                    (addNote = new RelayCommand((o) => 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(NewNote.Title);
                    }));
            }
        }

        /*public IEnumerable<Note> Notes
        {
            get { return notes; }
            set
            {
                notes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Notes");
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            DB = new ApplicationContext();
            DB.Notes.Load();
            Notes = DB.Notes.Local.ToBindingList(); 
        }*/

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));

        }
    }
}
```

Veiw:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.85*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Margin="25, 40, 50, 50" MinHeight="50" Text="{Binding ElementName=NewNote,Path=Title,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="25, 0, 50, 60" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=NewNote,Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="25, 0, 50, 30" MinHeight="50" Content="Add note" Command="{Binding AddNote}"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Класс RelayModel сюда вставлять не стал

Comment: Пару замечаний по вашему коду: 1. `Margin="25, 0, 50, 60"` - не удивляйтесь потом, что ваши элементы куда то смещаются. Используйте сетку и правильное позиционирование объектов! 2. Не обязательно вызывать `OnPropertyChanged` на каждом свойстве. Если свойство изменится через код (например `NewNote = new Note();`, то да, необходимость есть). Касательно вопроса - вы не правильно понимаете `ElementName`. Он создан для того, что бы связать XAML объекты. Например взять текст из одного `TextBox` и вывести его в другом. Вам же для работы с объектом внутри класса достаточно написать `NewNote.Title`.

Comment: Спасибо! А как в моем случае лучше поступить с отступами? Будет ли корректно добавить вместо margin элемент сетки?

Comment: Если взглянуть на ваш [макет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVZ0.png), то видно как минимум то, что они имеют общий отступ и сетка используется только слева. По этому лучше будет сделать что то на подобие [этого](https://pastebin.com/vV3HfsDf). Вся суть тут в том, что элементы, как бы мы их не двигали, [останутся](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJJnn.png) на своем месте, чего вашему макету явно не [хватает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXg7O.png).

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо